# pipで常にユーザー権限でインストールする方法

Tags: python, pip

お世話になります。
pipで

```
pip install [パッケージ名] --user
```

のように指定すると、ユーザー権限でパッケージをインストールできると思います。
ただ、毎回--userオプションを指定するのは少し大変なので、できれば常にユーザー権限でインストールしたいと考えています。
rubyのgemの場合、.gemrcに

```
gem: "--user-install"
```

と書いておけば、常にユーザー権限でインストールされるようですが、pipでも同じようにする方法はありますでしょうか。
少し説明がわかりづらいかもしれませんが、何かご存知でしたら、教えていただけると幸いです。
ちなみに、環境はLinuxですが、自分で作成したサーバーではないため、OSは不明です。
以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`~/.config/pip/pip.conf` (Windowsなら `%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini`) ファイルにこのように書いてください。

```
[install]
user = yes
```

参考: [Configuration | pip User Guide](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#configuration)

Comment: お世話になります。
お教えいただいた方法でうまくいきました。
ありがとうございました。